# Formula for velocity of magnets depending on their weight and strength in Magnetic Repulsion

Tags: electromagnetism

Given 2 similar magnets, each having mass $m_0$ (any convenient shape, say small cylinders) held together (flat sides N-N or S-S facing each other) by force (to counter their physical repulsion) in a hollow glass tube (so they travel in a straight line). Let the magnetic strength of each magnet be $h_0$ (whatever be the appropriate unit).

When the physical contraption is removed they travel in opposite direction from the origin. Each magnet travels a certain distance $d_0$ from the origin in time $t_0$.

In an ideal case scenario (ignoring all the other external factors like friction etc.) how does the time taken to travel the distance $d_0$ change with change in the magnet's mass and strength?

Can someone help with a formula?

Note: We are assuming both magnets as equal.

Comment: can someone please help?

Comment: To get the repulsive force as a function of the distance between the centers of the magnets go to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets , then scroll to section “Magnetic-charge model” , subsection
“Calculating the magnetic force” , sub-subsection
“Force between two magnetic poles”

Comment: Good find, Al Brown...

Comment: @AlBrown thank you for your reply. But i am afraid I still have doubts: 1. Given the fact the force is at a particular instance but the magnets are moving [that motion changes the magnetic field as well as the opposing magnetic field due to motion] makes the thing very dynamic so I am still struggling with the formula for actual time taken to travel a certain distance [we can assume some distance d] based on the changes in charge and mass [taking all these factors into account. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @J.Doe yes i didnt mean to imply that would solve the problem. I’ll make some notes below

Comment: Also im not certain how the q works and where measured. There might be a standard always the same. Should be easy to figure out. But if at the surface then r starts at 0 at t=0, and if in the centrr then r is L at start (L/2 from one center to edge and L/2 to the other center, if same length).

Comment: i think that is a little bit of complication as mass would be center of mass but charge at surface. but that can be set aside since for large distance w.r.t. we might be able to ignore that part if i am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume they’re horizontal so that gravity is not part of it, and they said an ideal situation so we don’t have friction either. Just one force.

$$F=ma=  \frac{\mu q_1 q_2}{4 \pi r^2 (t)}= \frac{k q_1 q_2}{r^2 (t)}$$

where $r$ is a function of time, and as per the equation force is too. But the equation assumes constant $q$’s (handles distance via $r$). The force between two magnets is a function of distance; don’t worry further about fields. The fields change with distance to give that force. There are no dynamics perpendicular to the fields and motion (velocity parallel to field) so the right hand rule lets you ignore the effects of speed on force.

$$a= F/m = \frac{k}{r^2 (t)}$$

Different k. To solve this use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3928053/955529
But stop before “From here..” because thats the answer.

That’s the limit until/unless you have questions. Details to work out for sure. Limits for integral etc. Plus I have to go. Does that help?

Comment: The problem states *"any convenient shape, say small cylinders"*, that is bar magnets. Then $F(r)$ is a lot more complicated than $\propto 1/r^2$...

Comment: thanks a lot again. was of great help. just so if i interpret it correctly (in the horizontal case) say for cylindrical magnets [approximately] : Case 1: If I have 2 charges with mass $m$, charge $q$ each.  Case 2: If I have charge $k*q$ each and mass $k^2$. In both these cases the time $t$ taken to travel distance $d$ should be the same. just a reconfirmation?

Comment: @Gert thank you. as long as its an ok approximation for calculating 'change in $t$' w.r.t. 'change in $m$ and $q$' it shouldn't be a problem [for some distance 'd']. but if there is even a better approximation please let me know.

Comment: @J.Doe You'll find it id the link Al Brown provided.

Comment: @Gert thank you. will check.

Comment: @J.Doe im around for a bit again, and maybe later if questions

Comment: @AlBrown   just that 1 Q above in comment 'just so if i interpret it correctly (in the horizontal case)..' (as of now) to see if my interpretation is correct

Comment: Not quite. The magnetic charge is q. The constant k Im using is, that first time, $k = \mu / 4\pi$ , people will often take everything that doesnt change during the problem, along the motion in this case, and label it all as a constant. I did that again and shouldve used a different letter, like j, and said “where j is a constant and $j= \mu / 4\pi m$ . The second time $k= \mu / 4\pi m$  Because when youre doing the solving why keep writing that, none of those things change. But there are identical equations of motion for each mass (if same m and length L).

Comment: I think the k second time should be $k= \mu q_1 q_2 / 4\pi m$ ?